# How to keep session alive while running the playbook for longer period of time?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am running ansible playbook to restart some of our servers but we need to sleep for 40 minutes between each server restart so if I sleep for 40 minutes in my playbook then it sleeps for a while but then my session gets terminated on Ubuntu box in prod and whole script is also stopped. Is there anything I can add in ansible playbook so that it can keep my session alive during the time whole playbook is running?

```
# This will restart servers
---
- hosts: tester
  serial: "{{ num_serial }}"
  tasks:
      - name: copy files
        copy: src=conf.prod dest=/opt/process/config/conf.prod owner=goldy group=goldy

      - name: stop server
        command: sudo systemctl stop server_one.service

      - name: start server
        command: sudo systemctl start server_one.service

      - name: sleep for 40 minutes
        pause: minutes=40
```

I want to sleep for 40 minutes without terminating my linux session and then move to next set of servers restart.

I am running ansible 2.6.3 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your ansible script inside [screen](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_screen) in order to keep the session alive even after disconnection.

Basically what you want to do is ssh into the production server, run screen, then execute the playbook inside the newly created session.

If you ever get disconnected, you can connect back to the server, then run screen -r to get back into your saved session.

Comment: so if I run my ansible script inside screen session then it won't get terminated at all?

Comment: You might get disconnected from the server. But you can  reconnect to the server, run screen -r and your session will be back.

Comment: so lets say if I get disconnected but my ansible playbook will still keep running right? and I can check that by doing `screen -r` correct? when you say my session will be back, my playbook will be running in that session right?

Comment: Yes, you connect back to the server, then execute screen -r

Comment: If I don't connect back to the server for a while then still my playbook will be running right in that session? Just making sure.

Comment: Yes, you just need to reconnect to the screen session, you can try it yourself. ssh into your server, run screen, execute a command, disconnect from the server, reconnect to the server and lauch screen -r.